# Implicit cast to size_t?

Tags: c++, size-t

I want to know - does C++ do implicit cast when we initialize unsigned size_t with some value?
Like this:

```
size_t value = 100;
```

And does it make sense to add 'u' literal to the value to prevent this cast, like this?

```
size_t value = 100u;
```

Comment: Implicit cast will happen every time when type of the integer literal is different from the type aliased by `size_t`.

Comment: Nitpick: a cast is always explicit. There are implicit *conversions*.

Comment: It might make sense to add the `u` suffix for large numbers that are out of the `long long` range. Decimal integer literals have always a signed type. Live demo (check the generated compiler warnings): https://godbolt.org/z/vjvnzax83.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> does C++ do implicit cast when we initialize unsigned size_t with some
> value? Like this:
>
> ```
> size_t value = 100;
> ```

Yes. `std::size_t` is an (alias of an) integer type. An integer type can be implicitly converted to all other integer types.

> And does it make sense to add 'u' literal to the value to prevent this cast, like this?

There is still likely an implicit conversion with the `u` literal suffix since `std::size_t` is not necessarily (nor typically) `unsigned int`. It may be for example `unsigned long int` or `unsigned long long int`. There is a standard proposal to add integer literal for the `std::size_t` alias, but there doesn't exist one for now.

Using a matching literal doesn't matter much in this example, as long as the type of the literal can represent the value in question, and as long as the literal value doesn't exceed the bounds of the initialised type. Even the smallest integer types can represent 100. The choice is largely a matter of taste.

---

Note that "implicit cast" is a contradiction in terms. Cast is an explicit conversion.